# Check if format is YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to check if the format stored in an SQL table is YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Tag dbms used! (Too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: But why do you need to do that? Always use `date` data type for dates...

Comment: I am analysing an already existing dataset. I`ve tried : LIKE `%YYYY-MM-DD%` but bot sure if it`s correct.

Comment: More info? If the date is stored in a date/datetime column, there is no such thing as 'storage format'. The date and time parts are stored as numbers and displayed by a default rule configured. If it is a character column, then is 1999-01-02 valid? What if it is the 1st of February in 1999. Also the actual product would be nice to know (mysql, mssql, postgre) - with the version in use.

Comment: It`s imported from a DB2 environment and is stored as a date column. I would like to be able to identify where there are values like 0198-00-56 or 3456-34-56, if any.

Comment: Then it doesn't matter what it is displayed as, that depends on your local settings. If it's stored as a date then the format doesn't matter.

Comment: If it is stored in a date column, how it could contain values like 0198-00-56 or 3456-34-56? It can not unless the DATE type differs that much in the DB2 implementation.

Comment: select cast( yourcolumn as date) from yourtable  ... if you get 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time' then the format doesn't fit. In SQL the format YYYY-MM-DD coresponds to DATE

Comment: Values like *0198-00-56 or 3456-34-56* cannot be stored in a **date-typed** column! I'm quite sure, that the problem is somewhere else. Please show the definition of your table and the way you are filling it with values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this way

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE(@string) = 1 
  AND @string LIKE '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]' 
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

@string is date.

Answer (score 3):

You dont store specific format (i think ms sql stores it as two integers), you select your format for output. And when I say you select, I mean you have your default (mostly set automatically when installing MS SQL or whatever you use based on your country, timezone, etc - you can change this) and those which you choose to when executing scripts.

Comment: MS-SQL Server stores a date as float-number. Try this: `SELECT CAST({d'1900-01-01'} AS FLOAT) AS FirstPossible,CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT) AS CurrentDate`. The integer part is the count of days since 1900-01-01 and the part behind the comma is the day's time. That's the reason why the addition of times can lead to funny dates somewhere in January 1900 :-)

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost: If the date value is stored in `date` or `datetime` or equivalent temporal data type column there is no such thing as date format in the database level. The date itself was validated by the rules defined in the specific database engine's given data type and stored in whatever binary format it defines.

If the data is a STRING (from a file or a varchar column for example), then you can validate if it is in a given format using the `TO_DATE()` or `TRY_CONVERT()` functions in newer versions of SQL Server and `STR_TO_DATE()` in MySQL, or you can use 3rd party/self written modules/clrs to do it.

These validations will only check if the string maches the given format and the date parts are in the acceptable range of dates, but it will not test the meaning of the value. Converting the 02/03/2005 string to date is valid for the `MM/DD/YYYY` and `DD/MM/YYYY` format too, and there is no way to tell which one is the real value unless we have information about the environment originally stored it.

**NEVER EVER store temporal data in character based column (like varchar), use the data type matches your needs (DATE/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP/whatever).**

Comment: @Fully agree with a tiny *but*: You can store this character based if you use culture independent formats such as ODBC or ISO8601. Otherwise ther was no typesafe XML possible :-)

Comment: Partially agreed with the following comment: if you store it in character format, be consistent in the format and store all parts including the timezone in a reliable format (like the ones mentioned by @Shnugo), and only if the storage engine does not support temporal storage types (like XML mentioned already). In the answer, I am talking about databases, so the last comment meant to be about databases and not other storage formats.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do like this to check YYYY-MM-DD

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE regexp_like(invoice_date,'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$');
```

Explanation of the regular expression pattern:

- `^` asserts the start of the string.
- `\d{4}` matches exactly four digits (for the year).
- matches the hyphen character literally.
- `\d{2}` matches exactly two digits (for the month).
- matches another hyphen character.
- `\d{2}` matches exactly two digits (for the day).
- `$` asserts the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the format but as far as I know you cant check the format.

Answer (score 0):

try this to find format of values for date or varchar date field. Thanks

```
DECLARE  @Description VARCHAR(20)
SET @Description='200202'
SELECT CASE WHEN patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',@Description)=1 THEN 101 
            WHEN patindex('%[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',@Description)=1 THEN 110
            WHEN patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]%',@Description)=1 THEN 102 
            WHEN patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%',@Description)=1 THEN 111
            WHEN patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',@Description)=1 THEN 112
            WHEN patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',@Description)=1 THEN 103 
            WHEN patindex('%[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',@Description)=1 THEN 104
            WHEN patindex('%[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',@Description)=1 THEN 105
    ELSE 101 END
```

Answer (score 0):

This already has an accepted answer but I found a way to do this without regular expressions if anyone wants:

```
DECLARE @dateString VARCHAR(12) = '2023-05-12';

SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(@dateString AS DATE) IS NOT NULL AND @dateString = FORMAT(TRY_CAST(@dateString AS DATE), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
            THEN 'Valid'
            ELSE 'Invalid'
       END AS ValidationResult;
```

Hope it helps!